# numpy where with multiple conditions linked to dataframe

Tags: python, string, numpy

I'm using numpy where with multiple conditions to assign a category based on a text string a transaction description.

Part of the code is below

```
`import numpy as np

conditions = [
    df2['description'].str.contains('AEGON', na=False),                        
    df2['description'].str.contains('IB/PVV', na=False),                   
    df2['description'].str.contains('Picnic', na=False),                   
    df2['description'].str.contains('Jumbo', na=False),  
]    
values = [
    'Hypotheek',                                                  
    'Hypotheek',                                                  
    'Boodschappen',                                               
    'Boodschappen']   

df2['Classificatie'] = np.select(conditions, values, default='unknown')
```

I have many conditions which - only partly shown here.
I want to create a table / dataframe in stead of including every seperate condition and value in the code. So for instance the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

Conditions = {'Condition': ['AEGON','IB/PVV','Picnic','Jumbo'],
         'Value': ['Hypotheek','Hypotheek','Boodschappen','Boodschappen']
         
        }

df_conditions = pd.DataFrame(Conditions, columns= ['Condition','Value'])
```

How can I adjust the condition to look for (in the str.contains) a text string as listed in df_condictions['condition'] and to apply the Value column to df2['Classificatie']?
The values are already a list in the variable explorer, but I can't find a way to have the str.contains to look for a value in a list / dataframe.

```
    Desired outcome:
    In [3]: iwantthis
    Out[3]:
       Description               Classificatie
    0  groceries Jumbo on date   boodschappen         
1  mortgage payment Aegon.    Hypotheek
    2  transfer picnic.           Boodschappen
```

The first column is the input data frame, te second column is what I'm looking for.

Please note that my current code already allows me to create this column, but I want to use another more automated way using de df_condtions table.

I'm not yet really familiair with Python and I can't find anything online.

Comment: Can you please edit your question and put there sample (small) input dataframe and expected output?

Comment: I edited my question, did it clarify? @AndrejKesely
I found another similar topic in the mean time: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62854013/how-to-add-a-pandas-column-based-on-partial-string-match tried this, but it led to strange combinations, also when adjusting the cut-offs. But in essence it seems to be the same question

Comment: thanks. 
I get two errors:
1) InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects

and if I run again:
raise KeyError(key) from err

KeyError: 'Condition'
I had some duplcicates in the conditions table, which I removed. But the error keeps occurring.

I've added a verification of the integrity (both set tot TRUE and false), but this does not solve the issue
df_conditions = df_conditions.set_index('Condition', verify_integrity=False)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
import re

df_conditions["Condition"] = df_conditions["Condition"].str.lower()
df_conditions = df_conditions.set_index("Condition")

tmp = df["Description"].str.extract(
    "(" + "|".join(re.escape(c) for c in df_conditions.index) + ")",
    flags=re.I,
)

df["Classificatie"] = tmp[0].str.lower().map(df_conditions["Value"])
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
               Description Classificatie
0  groceries Jumbo on date  Boodschappen
1  mortgage payment Aegon.     Hypotheek
2         transfer picnic.  Boodschappen
```